# How to use Sugar API to fetch data from custom table

Tags: php, mysql, api, soap, sugarcrm

I want to fetch records just like mysql query using REST API of Sugar CRM.

I found a method to get records form custom module like below.
Get list of records from SugarCRM module using REST API:
http://scriptbaker.com/get-list-of-records-from-sugarcrm-module-using-api/

My problem is I don't have module with the table I am trying to fetch records. Is there any way .???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to get data from table which is not actually a module. 
The table does not exist in the SugarCRM models and configs, so the API cannot access it.

You can create a separate file to get the data from the table using SugarCRM db object.

If you give me some more detail info I can prepare such file for you.

Comment: Yeah I also searched a lot for it and end up with the same.

Comment: Thank you :) I am trying to make a separate file I will ask here if found any problem in that way.